# Distributed SQL Server Cache - connectionString

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching

Is it possible to change the SQL Server distributed cache connectionString at runtime? I'll exemplify my scenario:

1. > I'm using sessions to store user state.
2. > Sessions are saved in SQL Server Distributed Cache.
3. > Each user has a designated database.
4. > After login I need to store each user's session in their specific database, for this reason I must change the connectionString as different users log into the application.
5. > Method I need to change the connectionString [method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNQcQ.png)

It's possible ?

Comment: Its only Session Data why should every user has that in its own Database? Actual data is somewhere else right?

Comment: We are working with multitenant architecture using the database strategy, so I need each database to have a table where the cache can be stored. Among some searches, I still haven't found another way to do this.

Comment: Session is special inside the asp.net core, why you must use session state to store the user data?